# Slide whole <div>which contain only text with two control arrow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, slider

I made a website using Bootstrap. I want to add slider a in my website which slides a `<div>` which contain only text, not the image. Also, that slider contains two arrows for controls. Kindly suggest me a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slider example that may work for you. It has controls and is text only.

```css
.carousel {
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div id="carouselContent" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active text-center p-4">
                 <p>lorem ipsum (imagine longer text)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item text-center p-4">
                
                <p>lorem ipsum (imagine longer text)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselContent" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```